# ObjectDataSource which returns a DataSet with two or more tables

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, dataset, objectdatasource

I am writing my own ObjectDataSource SelectMethod as follows:

```
public class SomeDataprovider
{
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public DataSet GetData()
    {
        NWdbTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter a1 = new CustomersTableAdapter();
        NWdbTableAdapters.SuppliersTableAdapter a2 = new SuppliersTableAdapter();

        NWdb.CustomersDataTable dt1 = a1.GetTop10();
        NWdb.SuppliersDataTable dt2 = a2.GetTop10();
        dt1.TableName = "Table1";
        dt2.TableName = "Table2";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

There are two gridviews in the page:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="odsMultipleDataTables.SomeDataprovider">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to make "Table1" appear in GridView1 and "Table2" appear for GridView2 respectively. But when I do set the DataMember property on the grid, I get and error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

How is it possible to achieve what I am looking for?